# SQL importing data type query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, import, type-conversion

I am importing data into SQL using the import/export query wizard. I have a column with the following values

```
date_of_enqiury

2001-07-01 00:18:09.388991+00
1985-05-24 00:12:50.152856+00
```

What data type will I be importing the data in as? The data time offset returns an error.

Comment: Which import/export query wizard? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im using SQL Server and using the sql server import/export wizard. The right 3 characters ('+00') I've removed too and tried to import. But still no luck

Comment: nvarchar...i think.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use **datetimeoffset**

look [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for details.